# Understanding Python : UnboundLocalError

Tags: python

I have been using python for more than a year now but I am confused by something in this example:

```
def mul(x,y): return x*y

def setArg(f,a):
    def fx(*x):
        return f(*x,a)
    return fx

def test1():
    mul3=setArg(mul,3)

def test2():
    mul=4

def test3():
    mul=setArg(mul,3)

def test4():
    mu=setArg(mul,3)
    mul=mu
```

running test1 and test2 works fine,but running test3 and test4 give this error:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mul' referenced before assignment`

Can I only redefine mul inside a testX globally?
Why is so in python?
*using python3.7*

Comment: not entirely as I am more confused now due to 'nonlocal' in the answer

Comment: Ok, but the first paragraph of the answer explains the problem. Let me summarize it again: `mul = <some expression>` means that `mul` refers to a local variable and the assignment will give it a value. A variable (local or not) has no value before the first assignment. That's why `... = setArg(mul, 3)` expression fails to evaluate. Maybe this helps a little bit too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing#Python

Answer (score 4):

It's the argument 'mul' that is the problem, not the assignment to 'mul'. You can use both global and local with `mul=setArg(globals()['mul'],3)`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks ugly but it does work.